# Accessing Vars In All Script Tags In HTML Source Fetched Via xhr Request

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How would you access variable values from scripts tags in HTML source of a page fetched via xhr request.

HTML of fetched page...

```
<html>
   <body>
   <div id="somecontent"></div>
      <script>
        var foo="30";
      </script>

      <script>
        var bar="60";
      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

And fetched via xhr request...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://www.example.com/testpage.html");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var html = xhr.responseText;

    // try to access var 
    var result =html.foo+html.bar;

    console.log(result);

    } 

    }

   xhr.send();
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you fetch JSON instead of HTML?

Comment: No, it has to be full html pages and then extract specific vars/json objects from within the script tags...

Comment: I think @Armel's suggestion is probably the best you can do in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://www.example.com/testpage.html");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var html = xhr.responseText;
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var dom = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    var scripts = dom.querySelectorAll('script');

    for (let script of scripts) {
      eval(script.innerText);
    }

    console.log('foo', foo);
    console.log('bar', bar);
  }
}
xhr.send();
```